# Bokeh - How to make one single HoverTool for two data sources

Tags: python, bokeh

I've got a figure :

```
plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=1800, title="Volume [mL]",
              tools=["hover", "xpan", "reset", "box_zoom", "xwheel_zoom", "undo", "redo", "save"])
```

And I draw two lines on it:

```
prog = pvp_plot.line('timestamp_ms', 'volume_mL', source=ColumnDataSource(programmed),
                     line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, line_dash="dashed", color="black",
                     legend="Programmed")
exec = pvp_plot.line('timestamp_ms', 'volume_mL', source=ColumnDataSource(executed),
                     line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, color="red", legend="Executed")
```

I would like to have a single HoverTool popup which displays the two values (programmed vs executed) for the same timestamp.

If I try,

```
pvp_exec_hover_tooltips = [
    ("Time", "@timestamp_ms{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N}"),
    ("Programmed", "@volume_mL"),
    ("Executed", "@volume_mL")
]
```

it will display the same value @volume_mL twice. Which sounds correct as the tool does not know how to differentiate data. However, I want to keep my data formatted (and named) the same way, but still be able to discriminate it when displayed in HoverTool (something like @prog_volume_mL vs @exec_volume_mL). Can I do that without modifying my data format?

I managed to create two HoverTools but that's not ideal (they overlap most of the time, I could make it work to show one above cursor and one below, but what if now I have 3 lines, etc...).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could slightly abuse `CustomJSHover` to accomplish this. Unfortunately I don't have time at present to construct a full example.